# Writing an rsync shell script on Mac to continuously sync local directory with remote web server

Tags: shell, synchronization, cron, rsync, web-deployment

I need to set up a shell script on Mac OS X Mountain Lion to sync a local directory to a remote directory (web server) using either an SSH connection (tunnel) or SFTP and have it run continuously every 30 seconds.

I also need to exclude certain files or folders from being synced.

The syncing would be unidirectional (mac -> webserver).

The basic parameters I need to have implemented are as follows:

```
Local path: /Volumes/path/to/local/directory
Remote server: example.com
username: someUser
password: somePassword
Remote path: /path/from/server/root/to/htdocs
Files to exclude: '.ht*', '*.sublime-*'
Folders to exclude: 'cache','administrator/cache'
```

I would also need help writing the crontask and adding it to my system to execute automatically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

First, test that you can use ssh (login with user name and password):

```
$ ssh example.com
^D
```

Create an SSH key:

```
$ ssh-keygen
```

(don't enter a password)

This will create the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (private key) and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (public key files)

You'll need to transer the public key (`id_rsa.pub`) to your remote server (`example.com`) and then on the remote server, do the following:

```
$ cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ rm id_rsa.pub
^D
```

This adds the public key to the set of authorised keys.

You'll now be able to use ssh to connect to your remote server without having to use a username and password.

Next would be to use the rsync command, the following should suffice:

```
$ rsync -avz -e ssh 
     --exclude '*.ht*' --exclude '*.sublime-*' --exclude 'cache/' 
     --exclude 'administrator/cache'
     someUser@example.com:/directory/on/server /directory/on/local
```

(should be all on one line)

Now, once you've satisfied that this works for you, you want to put that command into a shell script (`rsync_script.sh`)

Then, you can use `launchctl` to schedule it:

In `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`, create `com.example.rsync.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.rsync</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>/path/to/rsync_script.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>30</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Couple of gotchas:

- Make sure that the rsync_script.sh is executable, i.e. do `chmod 755 /path/to/the/rsync_script.sh`
- Make sure that the user which created the SSH keys is the same user as sets up the `launchd` plist.

Comment: I am getting the following errors:
`-exclude '*.ht*' --exclude '*.sublime-*' --exclude 'cache/' 
-bash: --exclude: command not found`

Comment: @alisamii: had the order wrong, fixed now.

Comment: Now getting other errors. Tried it as you wrote (new line after ssh & after excludes) & rsync help was echoed. I put it all on 1 line and I got:

`stdin: is not a tty
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
 LANGUAGE = (unset),
 LC_ALL = (unset),
 LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
 LANG = (unset)
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
receiving file list ... done
sosdivorce/error_log

sent 4793 bytes  received 337204 bytes  62181.27 bytes/sec
total size is 98076766  speedup is 286.7`

Comment: Hi. I found something isn't working exactly as I wanted. The remote directory is called sosdivorce and the local directory is called sosd2. the full paths are remote: `/home/site/domains/clients/sosdivorce` and local: `/Volumes/sites/domains/clients/sosd2`. What is happening is that the entire remote directory _sosdivorce_ is being synced as a subdirectory of the _sosd2_ local directory. How do I get the contents of _sosdivorce_ to sync with the contents of _sosd2_?

Comment: The full command I am sending is: `rsync -avz -e ssh --exclude '*.ht*' --exclude '*.jpa*' --exclude '*.sublime-*' --exclude 'cache/' --exclude 'administrator/cache' ergonomi@ergonomiq.net:/home/ergonomi/domains/clients/sosdivorce /Volumes/Clients/htdocs/ergonomiq/domains/clients/sosd2`

Comment: Use `.../sosdivorce/` instead of `.../sosdivorce`.

Comment: Thanks. And I'm guessing that if I want to sync local to remote, I would reverse the order as such `/Volumes/Clients/htdocs/ergonomiq/domains/clients/sosd2/ ergonomi@ergonomiq.net:/home/ergonomi/domains/clients/sosdivorce`? And is there any way to have the syncing happen both ways?

Answer (score 2):

1. You should consider ssh key authentification instead using username/password, since you would have to store them in clear text. [SSH key authentification howto](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/530)
2. Create a file with your excludes and call it eg. `excludeList.lst` (see [rsync exclude files - examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/rsync-exclude-files-and-folders/)
3. The command for the `rsync` is something like this (read the docs: `man rsync`, there are tons of examples, including solutions to your problem too)

   rsync -avz --exclude-from 'excludeList.lst' /Volumes/path/to/local/directory -e ssh somUser@example.com:/path/from/server/root/to/htdocs
4. Test the script
5. Add `cron` [cron job - every 30 seconds](http://forum.slicehost.com/index.php?p=/discussion/2767/is-it-possible-to-run-a-cron-task-every-30-seconds/p1) or `launchd` [Run script every 30 seconds on a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/241972/run-script-every-30-seconds-on-mac):

Btw. you could've done this research too…

Comment: Hi, I did try to search, but I got so lost in translation that I was more confused afterwards. Sorry if I asked a question that may have already been answered many times.